# Can I break power steering by turning too far

Tags: power-steering, steering, steering-wheel

Will I damage power steering in a 2008 Camry XLE if I routinely turn the steering wheel to its limits, i.e. where it will not move further?

Answer (score 4):

This is called "cramping" the steering and it is bad for the pump and for the steering rack. What you are doing is forcing the system to *try* and push the steering components further than what they are meant to go. This causes over pressure on the pump (you may hear a slight squeal sound of the belt as the pump momentarily stalls), and it creates a bind in the steering rack as it is being forced to go beyond its limits. This also can over heat the fluid causing it to deteriorate quicker, and you probably guessed it wears out the serpentine belt sooner. All-in-all, not good.

Comment: Indeed - the handbook for my current car specifically says "Do not hold the steering wheel at full lock for more than 60 seconds as this can cause damage to the power steering system" (or words to that effect)

Comment: Wow , didnt know that nice question and answer.